# Add someone as watcher to github repo

Tags: github

How do I add someone as a watcher to my github repo?

Note:

- The repo belongs to an org
- The repo is private

Comment: they add themselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the comment, you can consider the [GitHub API on Activity Watching](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/activity#watching)

That API allows to list watchers, or for an authenticated user to "[set a repository subscription](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/activity#set-a-repository-subscription)".
But that call cannot be done "for another user", only for the current authenticated account.
This assumes, in your case, that account has access to the org and the private repository.

If there is no API allowing to add another user as watcher, it is probably not an existing feature.